# 钻法律的空子和钻法律的漏洞有差？

Tags: grammar, vocabulary, usage

我上课时遇到了这两个词， 但我还不太理解这两个有没有差别？

我知道它们在英文里指的都是”loophole“

I'm still not clear on what the difference is between these two! If you could give an example of how to use either, that would be really helpful!

谢谢！

Comment: iciba's examples might help correct collocation (词的搭配):漏洞 hole (in theory), gap (in argument),空子 gap, opening (空隙）web search shows examples using the combination  漏洞空子 or 漏洞，空子, which might have been used for emphasis  (1)没有十全十美完全安全且没漏洞空子可钻的方法的(2)加利福尼亚的法律有哪些漏洞、空子 ... 经济犯罪量刑我国法律有什么规定? (3). 政策的漏洞，空子 ... 资本区别的原理解读中国游资为什么 ...

Comment: (Just wanna say something irrelevant) Your title sounds as if you're Taiwanese :D

Comment: haha, I studied in Taiwan. Darn you Taiwan!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

漏洞 is just more formal than 空子。 If two guys are talking on the street, they may use 空子. But if you are writing on some files, you'd better use 漏洞. Other than this, they basically mean the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

没有差别，但是中国比较习惯说钻法律的空子，利用法律的漏洞。如果说有差别，第二个比较官方一点吧